# iTunes Helper still running even if it is off

Tags: macos, itunes, mac

I want to disable iTunes Helper.

I have remove it from `Settings > Users & Groups > Login Items`, but it's still running after restart.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

iTunesHelper will run if you open iTunes, or do something that opens an iTunes service.

The only way to completely disable iTunesHelper is to…

1. Quit iTunes and remove iTunesHelper from Login Items.
2. Go to `/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/`

   - You can use Finder's Go to Folder to go there - paste in the path as above.
3. Rename iTunesHelper.app to something else (e.g. iTunesHelper-disabled.app).

iTunesHelper should not run automatically now.

Comment: Using this method, you will get an occasional warning that iTunesHelper can not be found (at least for me on Sierra).

Comment: Can't seem to rename this file... is there a trick?

Comment: @gmc It's protected by System Integrity Protection in recent macOS, you'll need to [disable SIP](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/package-incompatible-installer/) first (can be re-enabled after making the change).