# Prevent iTunes from opening when connecting bluetooth speaker

Tags: itunes, macos, bluetooth

I did read [iTunes keeps starting automatically](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110685/itunes-keeps-starting-automatically) but since I don't have the console output mentioned in this thread I don't know how to pin down the problem. So iTunes keeps opening when connecting my speaker (UE Boom) via Bluetooth. I did read that iTunesHelper could cause this. So I quit the process in Activity Monitor, removed it from the login items and renamed the application as suggested in [iTunes Helper still running even if it is off](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91710/itunes-helper-still-running-even-if-it-is-off). But iTunes still keeps starting, iTunesHelper doesn't it seems as I cannot see it in Activity Monitor anymore. I am running Mavericks 10.9.5 and have iTunes 12.1.0.50 installed. What can I do to prevent iTunes from starting automatically?

Comment: have you read this thread? http://superuser.com/questions/31925/what-can-i-do-to-stop-the-play-pause-button-from-opening-itunes
Maybe the Speaker "presses" play on connect.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it did not work. I guess I should contact their support although I heard that they don't have a solution to it either.